# How can I identify why my apache server getting killed once in every few days?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 lts vps (Contabo) with apache installed. Basic install, nothing really edited or configured.
Every few day, the apache gets killed by the OOM killer and I don't know what happens. It's totally random.

Here are the htop before the kill:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgegN.png)

Some apache process start using a lot of memory making it oom kills at Tue Dec 12 14:27.

Here are the access log if it helps: https://pastebin.com/VHuyXnnk
and the error log: https://pastebin.com/13jKxVe9

Let me know if you need any more log or anything.

How can I find out why this happens? Thank you in advance for any idea.

Comment: The OoM killer kills the “best” application when your system runs out of memory (and that is not always the application that is the immediate cause of the system running out of memory) to prevent your system from crashing hard and by default logs the reasoning for selecting Apache httpd in the kernel ring buffer. Display with `dmesg` or check the appropriate log file for kernel messages. In general either add swap space (as a stop gap) or more real RAM memory to prevent your applications from running out of memory OR add stricter limits to the amount of memory your apps can consume

Comment: Here is the dmesg https://pastebin.com/7KPj7fDB What's my problem is that the server should have been in idle and apache used all of the ram.

Answer (score 1):

According to your htop screenshot you're running at 100% memory and 45% swap use.

You're essentially overcommited on memory, and the oom killer has to reap some process to reduce memory pressure.

You can add more memory, spread the workload or reduce the workload by optimizing delivery and caching, or similar.

Comment: Yes I know this. When I had 100% memory use, the system did not do anything. I want to discover what happens with apache when that happens, its not normal that apache eats almost all 32gb of ram when I think it's in idle. Maybe some bots exploiting some common apache bug?